# Developing/Running more than one product on one device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am fairly new to Xcode and iOS development. I've been working on a couple of projects.

From what I understand, there's no way to package up a project and install it permanently on my iPhone without submitting it to the app store. If I install it for debug purposes using a dev license, it expires after 7 days. Have I missed something? Or is this correct? I have a friend with a paid up developer license who has added me to his team, so I have gotten around the 7 day issue.

I noticed that when I started working on a second project, installing it to the iPhone replaced the first app. I made sure they both have different bundle identifiers, but still, running one project on the device replaces the other one. Is there any way to mark these as different products and hence install both at the same time?

Thanks in advance for any advice/info given.

Comment: project with development profile with device uuid work fine on device until we delete it. also please double check your bundle identifiers and make sure it is different in the case on replacing the older project by installing new one.

Comment: After another clean build, it seems the different bundle identifiers may have solved the issue. I now have both apps on the iPhone. Thanks.